# Rails: Syntax error: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, ajax

I am new to using ajax in ruby on rails. What I want: If a user clicks on a link with the class `.link` (to an external site, e.g. www.google.de), it should send data - namely the `$(this).attr('id')` - to my rails controller#action in posts/view. This is working fine (!), nevertheless I got a syntax error:

> parsererror SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data
>   Stack-Trace:
>       jQuery.parseJSON@http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.self-660adc51e0224b731d29f575a6f1ec167ba08ad06ed5deca4f1e8654c135bf4c.js?body=1:9008:10
>       ajaxConvert@http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.self-660adc51e0224b731d29f575a6f1ec167ba08ad06ed5deca4f1e8654c135bf4c.js?body=1:9332:19
>       done@http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.self-660adc51e0224b731d29f575a6f1ec167ba08ad06ed5deca4f1e8654c135bf4c.js?body=1:9786:15
>       .send/callback@http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.self-660adc51e0224b731d29f575a6f1ec167ba08ad06ed5deca4f1e8654c135bf4c.js?body=1:10303:8
>       fakeviews.self-2c717c6e0cc666118cfc1f98874e4c23dad3ccc9e219b4a857306ed44e947a7b.js:16:25

This is my assets/javascripts/views.js.erb

```
$(document).on("click", '.link', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        url: "/posts/view", 
        cache: false,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { post_id: id }, // Here seems to be the problem?
        complete: function() {},
        success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
            alert("error");
        }
    });
});
```

When I delete the `dataType: "json"` the syntax error disappears. So what is going on exactly (since my code is working like I want, I am still wondering why there is the syntax error)?

**This is my controllers/posts_controller.rb view action**

```
def view
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @post.views.create(user_id: current_user.id)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to posts_path }
    format.js {render json: @post }
  end
end
```

Comment: The response being sent is not valid JSON. Can you edit your question to include the responseText from the request.

Comment: `dataType` refers to the data type that the server is supposed to send back to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to first serialize your object to JSON, and then specify the content-type so your server understands it's JSON.

```
$.ajax({
             url: "/posts/view", 
            type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': "application/json"
        }, 
        data: JSON.stringify({ post_id: id }),
```

The syntax error while parsing is raised because Rails can't recognize passed data (since it's not a valid JSON string).

- `contentType` specifies the format of data being **sent to the server** as
  part of request
- `dataType` specifies the expected format of data **to be received by the client**(browser).

**Also change the method from `GET` to `POST`. `GET` requests (at least usually) do not have a message body. If you're set it to `GET` it will be converted to parameters of URL string.**

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply :). I have changed my code as you've suggested and the syntax error is gone. However now my rails posts#view controller action does not seem to find the correct `Post` anymore. Do I have to change something in there too (I've included my rails controller#action in my question)? And in the Javascript console now I get the error **error Not found**.

Comment: Did you check the rails log, which payload passed to the action? _Also StackOverflow is not your debuging tool, try to understand the problem_.

Comment: In my rails logs I get this error: ´Completed 404 Not Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Fpost with 'id'=):´

Comment: I say about the parameters which passed to the action.

Comment: whoops, sorry. These are the parameters passed to the action: **Processing by PostsController#view as JSON
  Parameters: {"{\"post_id\":\"635\"}"=>nil, "_"=>"1483539580899", "post"=>{}}**

Comment: @OhDaeSu looks like the headers didn't set properly, I updated the answer, try it again, note about two options, remove `cache: false` and add the `headers`.

Comment: Awesome, that was it. Thank you. And of course in my routes.rb I changed `get 'posts/view' => 'posts#view'` to  `post 'posts/view' => 'posts#view'`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `data` should be a valid JSON string. You can verify if it's valid [by pasting it here](http://jsonlint.com/). To achieve a valid JSON string in your case, use `JSON.stringify(JavaScriptObject)`:

```
$(document).on("click", '.link', function() {

var id = $(this).attr('id');
var dataObject = {};
dataObject.post_id = id;
$.ajax({
    url: "/posts/view", 
    cache: false,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(dataObject)
    complete: function() {},
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        alert("error");
    }
});
});
```